# CSS diagonal mousemove fill on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fill a button with a diagonal effect on the mousemove (so the button is filled where the mouse is)

I have the effect of a diagonal fill on a hover:

```css
.demo {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
.mt {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.small {
  width: 120px;
}
.medium {
  width: 160px;
}
.large {
  width: 230px;
}
.extra-large {
  width: 360px;
}
.diagonal {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  background: white;
  font-weight: book;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0px;
}
.diagonal:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 30;
  left: 0;
  width: 500%;
  height: 1000%;
  background: #F5FF35;
  z-index: -1;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translateX(calc(-130% - 0px)) translateY(10%) rotate(45deg);
  transition: transform 1s;
}
.diagonal:hover::after {
  transform: translateY(-100%) translateX(-50px) rotate(45deg);
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <a class="mt small diagonal">Click me!</a><br>
  <button class="mt medium diagonal">Click me!</button><br>
  <button class="mt large diagonal">Click me!</button><br>
  <button id="demo" class="mt extra-large diagonal">Click me!</button>
</div>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPqBoR)

But I can't set it up on a mousemove, I have found something similar from an other question, [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdq5z7ej/1/).

Basically, I am trying to fit the codepen and the jsfiddle together

I tried to rotate the div in the jsfiddle but the fill effect would be all over instead of only the start, plus it would not cover the whole area..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
   $('.green').on('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (e.pageX < $(this).width());
  var percent = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left * 100 / $(this).width();
  $(this).css({
    'background': 'linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) ' + percent + '%,rgba(0,0,0,0) ' + (percent + 0.1) + '%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)'
  });
});
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/sdq5z7ej/4/

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by mostly adjusting the CSS, basically rotating that green div.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
var child = document.getElementById('child');
parent.addEventListener("mousemove", fill);
parent.addEventListener("mouseleave", hasLeft);

function fill(e) {
  if (e.x <= parent.offsetWidth) {
    child.style.width = e.x + 'px';
  }
};

function hasLeft(e) {
  if (child.offsetWidth === parent.offsetWidth) {

  } else {
    child.style.width = '0px';
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}
#parent {
  height: 65px;
  width: 100px;
  transform: scale(2) rotate(-45deg);
}
#child {
  height: 65px;
  width: 0;
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class='orange' id='parent'>
    <div class='green' id='child'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/3Loqende/)